# Delegate Using "this"

Tags: c#, delegates

I'd like to create a class that has overrideable methods in the form of delegates.

I basically would like to create an interface, but not have to create a new class every time I want to make it slightly different.

Further, I would like to bundle the delegate with a number of other variables in a struct.

Now here are some more specifics.

```
class Gun
{
    public delegate void ShootDelegate;

    // There are more variables, I'm just using this one as an example    
    public double fireRate; 

    public Gun(GunStats stats) 
    {
        this.Shoot = stats.Shoot;
        this.fireRate = stats.fireRate;
    }

    public ShootDelegate Shoot;
}

struct GunStats
{
    public ShootDelegate Shoot;
    public double fireRate;
}
```

then, what I'd like to be able to do is make a gun like this

```
GunStats stats;
stats.fireRate = 3;
stats.Shoot = new delegate() { this.fireRate++; /* stupid example */ };
new Gun(stats);
```

however, when I create the delegate, it obviously can't interact with the inner class variables.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Create a Event for this delegate and fire the event ...

Comment: @AravindSrinivas: I'm sorry, I don't follow at all.

Comment: What you dont follow .. i cant get u

Comment: I think you should reconsider your stance on creating additional classes. That's the whole point of OOP. As it happens, delegates are just classes where the compiler generates code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a reference to a `Gun` object in the delegate.
Change delegate to:

```
public delegate void ShootDelegate(Gun g);
```

Then you can do this:

```
GunStats stats;
Gun g = new Gun(stats);
stats.fireRate = 3;
stats.Shoot = new delegate(g) { g.fireRate++; };
```

Comment: Or if you want to get at the `fireRate` of `GunStats` you can use the same idea.